# How to prevent other application to access my widget provider

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-broadcast

I have widget provider which is declared in manifest like this:

```
            <receiver
            android:name=".widget.MyWidgetProvider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/widget_label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_buttons" />
            </receiver>
```

How i can prevent other apps to access my widget provider with explicit intents? I can't set `android:exported="false"` because according to documentation `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` needs to be usable from outside.

Update: I was wrong. Apparently it's ok to set `android:exported="false"` which is a bit confusing because intent-filter `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` has to be declared anyway.